# How to make a get request to an external website and display data via express

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I am trying to make a get request to a simple website, and display the "phrase"'s value

here is what i have for index.js

```
router.get('https://corporatebs-generator.sameerkumar.website/', function(req, res, next) {
      res.render({corporateMessage :req.query});
  });
router.get('/', function (req, res, next) {
  res.render('index', { title: 'The corp'});

})
```

Here is what i have for my index.hbs

```
<h1>{{title}}</h1>
<p> {{corporateMessage}}</p>
```

I just want to be able to display the message thats in the 'phrase', and have it shown in the above html format, not sure what to put in the `req.query` part.. little confused

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `request` to get the response from external path like this:

```
var request = require('request');
router.get('/path', function(req, res){
    request({url: 'https://corporatebs-generator.sameerkumar.website/', json: true}, function (error, response, body) {
        res.render('index', {
            corporateMessage: body.phrase
        })
    });

})
```